# why got exception java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificate has been denied

Tags: debugging, exception, https, applet, certificate

when use jre1.7 to access https in ***some*** enviroment, it prompts java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificate has been denied

The applet is simple, such as

applet codebase="https://xxx.xx.com/CheckJava.class"

The error seems for security reason, jre doesn't allow any class or jar to download.

if change the https to http on codebase, it works.

Very appreciated if you could provide any clue to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks Satya, it's no use. Just found it's a JRE1.7.0.5 issue, when upgrade to the latest one JRE1.7.0.6, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> Just found it's a JRE1.7.0.5 issue, when upgrade to the latest one JRE1.7.0.6, the problem is gone.